# PayPal subscription and webhooks

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I made an website with a service that I am charging for. I want to create a PayPal subscription. I need that subscription to be connected with my backend (firebase functions - node.js) so I can change some data in the database to serve my users different content depending if they are paying or not. I wanted to use PayPal buttons for my subscription but I can't find a way to connect that button with my backend so it seems PayPal buttons aren't optimal for my problem. I can't use Stripe because it's not supported in my country. Can you offer me a different solution for my subscripton payments or show how can I use PayPal?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Paypal Node SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) for your use case instead of relying to the embeddable Paypal subscribe button. The SDK will give you better integration with NodeJs.

There are basically 2 steps to do this:
**1.) Define the Billing Plan Object**
The billing plan object defines the subscription plan, including the number of cycles, frequency of payment, any setup fees, and so on.

```
var billingPlanAttribs = {
  name: 'Food of the World Club Membership: Standard',
  description: 'Monthly plan for getting the t-shirt of the month.',
  type: 'fixed',
  payment_definitions: [{
    name: 'Standard Plan',
    type: 'REGULAR',
    frequency_interval: '1',
    frequency: 'MONTH',
    cycles: '11',
    amount: {
      currency: 'USD',
      value: '19.99'
    }
  }],
  merchant_preferences: {
    setup_fee: {
      currency: 'USD',
      value: '1'
    },
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel',
    return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/processagreement',
    max_fail_attempts: '0',
    auto_bill_amount: 'YES',
    initial_fail_amount_action: 'CONTINUE'
  }
};
```

Of course, you will need to change cancel_url and return_url to your actual Firebase functions endpoints (or localhost if you are running your functions in localhost for development purposes)

**2.) Create and Activate Billing Plan, so once you created or defined your billing - you will need to create that object and activate the billing plan like so:**

```
paypal.billingPlan.create(billingPlanAttribs, function (error, billingPlan){
  var billingPlanUpdateAttributes;

  if (error){
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    throw error;
  } else {
    // Create billing plan patch object
    billingPlanUpdateAttributes = [{
      op: 'replace',
      path: '/',
      value: {
        state: 'ACTIVE'
      }
    }];

    // Activate the plan by changing status to active
    paypal.billingPlan.update(billingPlan.id, billingPlanUpdateAttributes, function(error, response){
      if (error){
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        throw error;
      } else {
        console.log('Billing plan created under ID: ' + billingPlan.id);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Again, all of these are documented in [Paypal's Developer Section](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-plan/#create-and-activate-billing-plan).

[Here's also a link to their github example using NodeJs](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/tree/master/samples/subscription) (which is same underlying backend as a Firebase Function)

Comment: What if I don't have predefined number of cycles I just want it to be infinite, what should 'cycles' be set at? @Raven

Comment: Why is PayPal-node-SDK repository archived? Is it that old and unreliable?

Comment: And also how can I connect my firebase users with payments? How can I now which payment/subscription is from which users?

Comment: @PyFran the cycles are how often payment is taken while the user is subscribed. The PayPal node SDK might be archived because it was replaced by a newer SDK. Finally, as Raven pointed out there is documentation on everything on PayPal's website; You have the ability to register and store whatever data you need with the events that get called from the PayPal Subscription.